# Java Error in String Split

Tags: java, string

I want my program to accept search strings, for example:
blue & berry (to find both of the words)
bed | sleep | pillow(to find first one or the second one etc)
When i recieve these string into my program, i use
String.split() With "&" or "|" as separator.

```
String[] splited = input.split("|");
```

It works fine in the first case, but in the second case in separates each letter in the words, for example: b  e  d. Can i do something for it to be separated by words with this symbol,  not just splited letter by letter?

Answer (score 5):

`split()` is taking a regexp as argument. `|` means or, so you are splitting on "empty string or empty string", so it's splitting after every letter. If you want to split on "|" symbol, you have to escape it:

```
String[] splited = input.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 3):

`String.split(String)` uses regular expressions and | is a special character in regex. Use `\|` to refer to a literal `|`, and `\\` to escape the `\` for Java. Resulting in `\\|`.